# cygwin compiler to compile ruby file.c error

Tags: ruby, cygwin

I am tryint to compile ruby 2.0.0-p535 using the compiler cygwin. I have cygwin installed and running. I compiled cygdrive/c/Source/ruby-2.0.0-p353. When trying to compile the file using the make function i get this error.

```
compiling load.c
compiling proc.c
compiling file.c
file.c:4184:47: error: conflicting types for ‘GetLastError’
extern unsigned long __attribute__((stdcall)) GetLastError(void);
                                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/w32api/winbase.h:16:0,
             from /usr/include/w32api/windows.h:70,
             from file.c:18:
/usr/include/w32api/errhandlingapi.h:45:27: note: previous declaration of  ‘GetLastError’ was here
WINBASEAPI DWORD WINAPI GetLastError (VOID);
                       ^
Makefile:328: recipe for target 'file.o' failed
make: *** [file.o] Error 1
```

Any help is really appreciated. Let me know if any other information would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Goto this directory /tmp/ruby-build.2013xxxx/ruby-your version/. You will find the source code 
Modify the following:

```
--- /tmp/file.c 2014-05-13 15: 46: 16.129925200 +0900
+++ File.c 2014-05-13 15: 46: 56.862548100 +0900
@ @ @ @ -4126,7 Tasu4126,7

#ifdef __CYGWIN__
#include <winerror.h>
- extern unsigned long __attribute __ ((stdcall)) GetLastError (void); 
+ extern unsigned int __attribute __ ((stdcall)) GetLastError (void);
#endif

static VALUE
```

then run:

```
make install
```

worked for me.